# Blender 3 disable render locally in a specific view layer

Tags: rendering, outliner, viewlayers

In the outliner, filters, there are two icons for viewport visibility, one of them (the eye symbol icon) disables the viewport visibility locally, meaning for the current view layer, without affecting the other view layers, the other icon (the monitor display symbol) disables the viewport visibility globally, meaning it will be disabled for all view layers.
However, for the render visibility, there's only the global option (the icon that looks like a camera), turning this on for an object, will hide it in render in all view layers, I can't find a way to turn the render off locally for a specific view layer.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found eventually 2 ways to do so, both methods work on collections, not objects, so you need to put the objects to hide in render in a specific view layer in a collection:
**First way (not recommended)**: while in the view layer you're targeting, right click the collection you want to hide in render, then choose Visibility > Hide in Render. I marked this method as not recommended, because it has no visual indication whatsoever in the UI !
If you use this method, and send the file to a coworker, or if you visit it later, there's no way to find out visually that this collection will not render in this view layer, the only way to check, is to right click every collection in the scene, and check the visibility sub-menu.
**Second method:** Which might be obvious for most, but it definitely wasn't for me, is the collection's checkbox, uncheck it and this collection will not show in render, the downside, is that this check box is a master switch, it will hide the collection in the viewport too, but at least it provides a visual indication that can be spotted easily.

I'm posting this question and answering it because I spent a good couple of hours trying to figure out a way to do this, call it a brain fart, may be, but there's definitely a UX/UI issue here that looks inconsistent in my opinion. So hopefully this will save some people's time.

Comment: Hi :). You got it right. The collection checkbox is meant exactly for this - removing from view layers

Comment: @JachymMichal however it has a problem, quoted  "toggling a collection on and off resets the visibility of ALL objects inside the collection. They don’t remember their state, which IMHO is a huge bug in the outliner, but that’s another topic."

Comment: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/amending-view-layers-to-track-local-render-visibility/11624/2

Comment: well, that seems intentional :). you need to 'disable' the objects using the 'screen icon' which remembers the state

Comment: The screen icon is labled "Disable in viewports"! Is it related to render?

Comment: No, it relates to viewport visibility, but it doesn't 'reset' when you switch collections on/off, unlike the 'eye' icon :)